# Advantage of Kotlin coroutine with webflux

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, project-reactor

I have a spring boot **Webflux** application. I am using **reactive Cassandra** in it. I have a scenario in which I have to do a query on two tables. One way is to just query them and combine both streams and process them.

I have also used **Kotlin coroutine** in one of the other projects with **spring boot MVC**. I am thinking of using coroutine in the Web flux application

My question is, is `it worth using Kotlin coroutines since Webflux works asynchronously?`, and unlike MVC, we do not need to explicitly manage asynchronous behavior until you are using a blocking function.

The only benefit I am seeing now is with coroutine by code looks **imperative** but behavior-wise it would be **asynchronous**.

Docs or articles are welcome regarding the usage of coroutine with spring web flux project reactor.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, but that is the main advantage, sequentially written asynchronous code.

Comment: Ok, if that's true then it is not worth it, as I have used reactive code at various places. Can you ping some doc regarding usage of coroutines with project reactor?

Comment: I have no experience with anything related to Spring. Just assuming the reactive API is similar to others.

Comment: Definitely worth using coroutines or combining with reactor. Sometimes it is hard to write clean code with reactor, like zipping multiple streams (for example calling many rest endpoints...). Imperative style is much more readable. On the other hand, there are tons of functions provided by reactor which you can use easily. Spring provides lot of bridge functions for mixed use, like mono, coRouter...